# How to print first child - sibling structure

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, nodes, siblings

I am trying to figure out how to print a first-child next sibling tree. What I want is the following:

```
root
|
firstChild - sibling - sibling
                       |
                       child - sibling - sibling
```

I have the following code to add childs and siblings :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GeneralTree<string> tree = new GeneralTree<string>();
        tree.root = new TreeNode<string>
        {
            Data = "Root"
        };
        TreeNode<string> child = tree.addChild(tree.root, "Child");
        tree.addSibling(child, "Sibling");
        tree.print(tree.root);
    }
}
class GeneralTree<T>
{
    public TreeNode<T> root;

    public TreeNode<T> addChild(TreeNode<T> parent, T data)
    {
        parent.FirstChild = new TreeNode<T>
        {
            Data = data,
            NextSibling = parent.FirstChild
        };
        return parent.FirstChild;
    }
    public TreeNode<T> addSibling(TreeNode<T> sibling, T data)
    {
        sibling.NextSibling = new TreeNode<T>
        {
            Data = data,
            FirstChild = sibling.NextSibling
        };
        return sibling.NextSibling;
    }

    int count = 0;
    public void print(TreeNode<T> Node)
    {

        if(Node !=null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Node.Data);
            print(Node.FirstChild);
            ++count;
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            print(Node.NextSibling);
        }
    }
}
class TreeNode<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public TreeNode<T> FirstChild { get; set; }
    public TreeNode<T> NextSibling { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone now how to print that out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a small example of how to print a tree

Comment: I described it above how i want to print it out

Answer (score 0):

I choosed to merge `TreeNode` and `GeneralTree` in this way :

```
public class TreeNode<T> 
{

    public T data;
    public List<TreeNode<T>> childs;

    public TreeNode<T> firstChild()
    {return childs.get(0);}

    public void appendChild(TreeNode<T> child)
    {childs.add(child);}

    public void print() {/* ... */}

    /* ... */

    public static void main(String args[])
    { /* ... */}
}
```

Then, a way to write `print()` recursively :

```
    public void print()
    {
        print(0);    
    }

    public void print(int offset)
    {
        if (node == null) return; // nothing to print anymore

        System.out.println(this.data); // printing the root data

        TreeNode<T> lastChild=null;
        String output = "";
        for(Iterator<TreeNode<T>> i = childs.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
        {   
            lastChild = i.next();
            if (output != "") output += " - ";
            output += lastChild.data;
        }

        // length will be the next line offset
        // (size of the current line output minus last item length

        int length = output.length()-lastChild.toString().length;
        // use a repeat() string function like this one :
        output = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.repeat(" ", length) + (length>0?"|":"") + output;
        System.out.println (output);
        lastChild.print(length);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately I can't validate my code right now, If you have issues, please let me know.

Comment: For the record, I use C# for coding this. I assume that my code is right qua structure, but the next thing I want to know is how to print it like a first child next sibling tree. If I print tree.root.FirstChild.NextSibling.Data I get the right sibling, so I think the code is not the problem, only the way how to print it out

Comment: Yes, you just have to check the print loop. What I understood is that you want to print all siblings, **then** last sibling's childs. Right? If you understand the process `(next offset = length(current_line) - length (lastSibling))`, you should be able to write your own function.

Comment: But in your case, each node could have more than 2 nodes because you use a list to store all its childs. That's not how a binary tree has to be constructed.

Comment: So why did you set up three childs in your print sample (first + two siblings)? Anyways, you can easily replace my `List` with what you want (`Node left`; `Node right;` for example). Just keep in mind that the main part is the `print` algorithm. (Also : I wrote in Java because you agreed the tag.)